# read multiple csv files and store content in separate variables with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an encoded input that is decoded based on data from 8 csv tables to produce output (write to HTML).
I am trying to read these 8 csv files into my script variables.
Something like this (not an actual code, just a logic I want to be implemented):

```
var str1 = table1.csv
var str2 = table2.csv
etc
```

I can use async xmlhtttprequest, but does not work for me because I need it to execute a bunch of code using the dataframe right after.

I edited the question, I will not use dataframes and just parse the csv files into arrays, but I still cannot read the csv files into variables.

I tried async but it only lets me handle each of the tables separately.
I tried arranging the code in a sequential style so that as soon as the input goes through the data of one table it then is passed onto the data from the next table but async does not work like that.

Consider this (again, not an actual code, just demonstrationn of logic I need implemented):

```
inputVar = 'ABCD1234ABCD1234'
var attribute1
var attribute2
var attribute3
etc 

df1 = table1.csv
df2 = table2.csv
df3 = table3.csv
etc

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  if (inputVar[i] == letter) {
     if(inputVar[i] == A) {
       attribute1 = df1["label"][i];
       attribute2 = df1["label"][i]/df2["label"][i];
       attribute3 = attribute3.push(df3[row])
     }
     if(inputVar[i] == B) {
       attribute1 = df2["label"][i];
       attribute2 = df7["label"][i]/df2["label"][i];
       attribute3 = attribute3.push(df3[row])
     }
     etc
  } else {
     output('wrong input')
  }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  if (inputVar[i] == number) {
     if(inputVar[i] == df5[label][0]) {
       attribute7 = attribute1 *10;
     }
     if(inputVar[i] == df5[label3][0]) {
       attribute1 = attribute1 *100;
     }
     etc
  } else {
     output('wrong input')
  }
}

output = attribute1; attribute2; attribute3; etc
```

There are many more logical gates that interconnect the values from different tables, and manipulate the data to produce the output.

I understand that python is preferable for dataframes and pandas has all this covered, but my project requires only js.

Comment: This seems to be the actual issue, but it's unclear: _But async does not work for me because I need it to execute a bunch of code using the dataframe right after_

Comment: It is my understanding that async lets the other code run while the function output has not been determined. That leads to my code run into error, because the output of the async is not yet implemented. If this is not true, and the async function will finish its work, and then lets the other code run, my apologies, I have created an issue out of nowhere then.

Comment: Can you please help me? It does not work with async either, when I try to access the values in the dataframe it returns that it is undefined.

Comment: Please add the relevant information to the question itself. For example, what kind of action are you trying to do "after" reading the data and how?

Comment: I added some more information. Thank you for returning to look at my issue.

Comment: I believe your overall logic and aim are clear. But your question should focus on the actual problem. Please include just the relevant part that corresponds to the actual issue: _I tried async but it only lets me handle each of the tables separately. I tried arranging the code in a sequential style so that as soon as the input goes through the data of one table it then is passed onto the data from the next table but async does not work like that._ Unless we see what doesn't work, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and willingness to help. I have solved the problem. It seems the main problem was my incorrect understanding of how an async function works and the insufficient understanding of the await keyword. Again, I am very grateful that you took the time to look at my issue and respond. I appreciate your patience with me, as I did not write the exact issue as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, will post the answer here for anyone who might run into same problem.

Step 1. Isolate the reading of csv files into a separate function that returns a promise. The promise resolves in the contents of the csv file in the form of string text.

Step 2. Make an async function that awaits the file before converting it into an array (or whichever format you need it in) and assign that value to a variable.

Step 3. Use the variables to make calculations using your dataProcessingFunction() inside (very important, the call to this function must be inside) the async function. That way your processing function will not start processing the data before it is done loading into variables.

```
function loadTable (file) {
   return new Promise (resolve => {
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {resolve(this.responseText)};
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
   });
}
        
async function getData() {
   var f1 =  await loadTable("table1.csv");
   var f2 = await loadTable("table2.csv");
   var f3 = await loadTable("table3.csv");
   //etc - however many you need;
   
            
   var df1 = f1.csvToArray();
   var df2 = f2.csvToArray();
   var df3 = f3.csvToArray();
   //etc - however many files you read above;
   
   
   dataProcessingFunction(df1, df2, df3);
}
    
getData();
```

It has to be done this way because ajax is by nature asynchronous, and if you do not adjust to that, your data processing function will start processing variables before they can be initiated with data from the files you are reading.

The two functions this block of code depends on (dataProcessingFunction and csvToArray) are not included because they are not that important in the issue discussed. One is the function processing data and that is going to be individual depending on what output do you want to produce, the second one (csvToArray) is a function that makes an array out of a string file based on parameters and that also will depend on your needs.